# Draw one SKPhysicsBody instead of more for tiles aligned next to each other

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit game I'm drawing platforms based on a 2 Dimensional Array. Platforms have a SKPhysicsBody created. 
Tiles aligned next to each other have issues with collisions, so I want to figure out what tiles are aligned next to each other and draw one SKPhysicsBody for those instead. So if a have something like this: 
(in my game the world platforms are vertical and gravity horizontal)

```
[
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0]
]
```

I want only one vertical SKPhysicsBody instead of 4. So im looking for a clever way to "see" tiles in the same column that are next to each other.

Comment: What if in your example, the top row was all 1's?  Would you want to have 2 physics bodies: one for the top row and one for the 3 in rows 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: why not solve this problem `Tiles aligned next to each other have issues with collisions`  instead so that you don't end up with logic that may end up get broken

Comment: I tend to agree with @Knight0fDragon.  This seems like an issue that will just keep popping up regardless of whether or not you lower the number of physics bodies.

Comment: @TrentSartain - It'll still be one. I only want to do it vertically. Player Glides with a constant speed and jumps on to the platform, while gliding the player colors the platform cubes. Its the Gliding Physics that has issues, and from a little googling research it has something to do with collision tests against the corners of a rectangular body. I will still need to make Bodies for each kube "as sensors" to detect that the player touches a cube and it should be coloured. Here is a video of my prototype: https://twitter.com/bjeld/status/660205525955645440

Comment: I Found ok solution for this.
Im creating GameObjects for each "1" in the 2Dimentional array. I then use "sort" to sort the items based on GameObjects column index.
Then i iterate and test if columns match and previous row index is near the current.